# Project Euler #6 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge

Question:

> Difference between the Sum of squares from 1 to 100 and the square of sums of 1 to 100.

Answer in Ruby:

```
range.inject(:+) ** 2 - range.map{|x| x ** 2}.inject(:+)
```

This one seems pretty straightforward but welcome any improvements to make it more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

The elegance of Mathematics:

```
def sum_below(n)
    n * (n + 1) / 2
end

def sum_squares_below(n)
    n * (n + 1) * (2*n + 1) / 2
end

limit = 1000
puts sum_below(limit) ** 2 - sum_squares_below(limit)
```

### The Math under  `n * (n + 1) / 2`

We have some natural numbers and we want to find their sum, the list is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4 ... n
```

Now we can note that the sum of `n + 1` is equal to the sum `(n - 1) + (1 + 1)` and is in turn equal to `(n - 1 - 1) + (1 + 1 + 1)`. In practice in the following

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

We can see that `1 + 6 == 2 + 5 == 3 + 4 == 7`.

We must repeat this (sum that equals `n + 1`)  (n / 2) times so we arrive to the final formula:

```
sum_below(n) = (n + 1) * n / 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't the sum_squares_below actually be n * (n + 1) * (2*n + 1) / 6 ?